# cross section for y=1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, cross-sections

My class has just started Multivariable, and I'd just gotten back my quiz results. However, I don't understand why for B), the correct graph is apparently in the other direction I thought it would be — from what I see from the graph of $f(x,y)$, shouldn't how I drew it be right (according to the axes labels I drew)? Any help would really be appreciated!

Also, I'm sorry for the second image. I'm not sure how to rotate it to put it right...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are correct. Maybe your professor got confused with the reversed (from a standard viewpoint) orientation of the $x$-axis.

Comment: @jjhh  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems correct, indeed from the 3D plot we can see that for $y=1$ we have that $z$ is strictly decreasing with $x$ increasing. To better visualize, the plot in the $x-z$ plane for $y=1$ is similar to $z=-x^3$.